# Is there any way to integrate coinbase with java?

Tags: java, coinbase-api

I was using below `code` to get the `response` but I Was getting the `403 error`

```
URL url = new URL ("https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/checkouts");

 Map map=new HashMap();

 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Comment: Note: you are using the raw type `Map`. **Never use raw types**, always provide type arguments for generic types.

Comment: Downvoted for no research. It is explained in their official API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it looks like you aren't providing enough information. There are two header fields that need to be supplied as well. These are `X-CC-Api-Key` which is your API key and `X-CC-Version`. See the link below.

https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/#introduction

Header fields can be provided to `HttpURLConnection` using the `addRequestProperty`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/checkouts");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.addRequestProperty("X-CC-Api-Key", "YourSuperFancyAPIKey");
connection.addRequestProperty("X-CC-Version", "2018-03-22");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

You also want to be careful about what method you use. You are supplying a POST method in your example. This probably not what you want to start with. If you send a GET method you will receive back a list of all checks. This will be a good place to start.

https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/#checkouts

- GET to retrieve a list of checkouts
- POST to create a new checkout
- PUT to update a checkout
- DELETE to delete a checkout

This type of API is known as REST.

Comment: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/checkouts

Comment: Did you replace YourSuperFancyAPIKey with your own token provided by coinbase?

Comment: Yes I have replace the key with my API key

Answer (score 1):

From https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/

> Most requests to the Commerce API must be authenticated with an API
>   key. You can create an API key in your Settings page after creating a
>   Coinbase Commerce account.

You would need to provide minimal set of information to API in order for it to respond back with success code `200`.

Comment: POST Response Code :  403
POST Response Message : Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/checkouts
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)